# Overlay closeable by a click outside

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a kind of window which pops up when a customer add a product to his/her cart. This is what it would look like : [Red and green divs are the background. There is a div which makes it darker (#overlay-daddy), and the white div is its child (#overlay).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SastM.png)

Using JS I added an event listener on #overlay-daddy which (is supposed to) set its display property to none. My problem is it also triggers an event when I click on #overlay. Thanks in advance !

Here's my code :

```css
#overlay-daddy {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 30%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/batiprox_common.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div style="height: 50%; background-color: red"></div>
  <div style="height: 50%; background-color: green"></div>
  <div id="overlay-daddy">
    <div id="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dad = document.getElementById('overlay-daddy');
    //dad.addEventListener("click", function() { this.style.display = "none";});
    dad.addEventListener("click", function() { alert(this); });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to disable the click event in the overlay's children, you need to test if the clicked element is the overlay itself, and not one of its children, with `if(event.target===this)` :

```css
#overlay-daddy {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 30%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/batiprox_common.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div style="height: 50%; background-color: red"></div>
  <div style="height: 50%; background-color: green"></div>
  <div id="overlay-daddy">
    <div id="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dad = document.getElementById('overlay-daddy');
    
    //dad.addEventListener("click", function() { this.style.display = "none";});
    
    dad.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      if(event.target===this) alert(this);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks !

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Also register a click handler on #overlay where you preventDefault();

Off the top of my head, that could look like this:

```
document.getElementById('overlay').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.cancelBubble();
   e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

Note that you probably don't need all three calls but it's been a while and my memory isn't clear on which you really need.

Comment: Exactly. Downvoted for this reason. OP doesn't use jQuery

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the event from being propagated. Just add `e.eventPropagation()` in the event listener for overlay.

```js
var dad = document.getElementById('overlay-daddy');
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

overlay.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

dad.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(this);
});
```

```css
#overlay-daddy {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 30%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 50%; background-color: red"></div>
<div style="height: 50%; background-color: green"></div>
<div id="overlay-daddy">
  <div id="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `click` event on your 'overlay' element is being propagated to its parent. You can add `event.stopPropogation` of your 'overlay' element.

You may modify your overlay element like below.

```
<div id="overlay" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code need bottom and right in #overlay-daddy

```
#overlay-daddy {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3; // edited
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0; // added bottom
  right: 0; // added right
}
```

So if you want to click in #overlay-daddy you need to set z-index for it greater than #overlay

I hope it can help you.

Comment: I believe you didn't understand the question. It was basically "How to prevent the click to trigger from the children, and only from the overlay itself?"

Comment: I agree with @JeremyThille. This is not the intended solution.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I don't understand this question.